# Interaction with whatsapp web using python

Tags: python, web, whatsapp

Is it possible to make a program in python in which the program will look for a message on WhatsApp sent by a particular person on a group(which I have pinned for convenience) at a particular time and then it will print the message sent by that person?

Well if you don't understand my question let me give you an example:

Suppose there is a group named ABCD which is pinned on WhatsApp web(which means it is at the top)

It consists of 4 people - A,B,C,D

I want the program to print the message sent by C at time 13:05 in that group

Is this thing possible on python?
I can use any module like selenium or even pyautogui

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible through Selenium without using any kind of API.

First we will import required modules:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
```

Now we will launch Whatsapp Web:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
```

You can use other browsers, for this example we will be using Chrome.

Now we will locate the Search or Start New Chat button using XPath and add a webdriver wait for it:

```
search_button = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search or start new chat']"))
```

Now we will click it and add a little sleep:

```
search_button.click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Now we will Send the name of the Person to contact into the text area:

```
search_button.send_keys("A")
time.sleep(2)
```

Now we will send a message

```
input_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//div[@class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text"][@contenteditable="true"][@data-tab="1"]')
time.sleep(2)
input_box.send_keys("Hello" + Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
```

You can using Chrome inspect more and do more things.